# Segmentation fault while running rails application in centos7

Tags: apache, ruby-on-rails-4, rvm

hello guys i am facing the problem while setup rails project aith apache-passanger.

i am facing the following error.

> /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json/ext/parser.so:
>   [BUG] Segmentation fault 
>       ruby 2.0.0p598 (2014-11-13) [x86_64-linux]

```
-- Control frame information ----------------------------------------------- 
c:0041 p:---- s:0123 e:000122 CFUNC :find 
c:0040 p:-5745760 s:0121 e:000120 TOP [FINISH] 
c:0039 p:---- s:0119 e:000118 CFUNC :require 

will you please guide me how to resolve it?
```